# how to read and write from .dat file in verifone

Tags: c, point-of-sale, verifone

I want to read and write a text or .dat file in verifone to store data on it.
How can I make it ?
here is my code

```
int main()
{
  char buf [255];
  FILE *tst;
  int dsply = open(DEV_CONSOLE , 0);
  tst = fopen("test.txt","r+");
  fputs("this text should write in file.",tst);
  fgets(buf,30,tst);

  write(dsply,buf,strlen(buf));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will rarely need to read from and write to a file at the same time, so don't use the `+` modes until you are familiar with file I/O. Instead, open the file with `"w"`, write to it, close it. Then open it again with `"r"`, read from it and close it. Make a habit of checking return values for error conditions and of pairing each `fopen` with a corresponding `fclose`.

Comment: how can i search in that file ? by wich command?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want. I guess that your question about reading and writing is wrong-headed. (If you want to have a database-like structure, load it into memory, operate on the database in memory and then commit it to file again. In any case, read a good tutorial on file I/O in C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 3 of the "Programmers Manual for Vx Solutions" ("23230_Verix_V_Operating_System_Programmers_Manual.pdf") is all about file management and contains all the functions I typically use when dealing with data files on the terminal.  Go read through that and I think you'll find everything you need.

To get you started, you'll want to use `open()` together with the flags you want

- `O_RDONLY` (read only)
- `O_WRONLY` (write only)
- `O_RDWR` (read and write)
- `O_APPEND` (Opens with the file position pointer at the end of the file)
- `O_CREAT` (create the file if it doesn't already exist),
- `O_TRUNC` (truncate/delete previous contents if the file already exists),
- `O_EXCL` (Returns error value if the file already exists)

On success, open will return a positive integer that is a handle which can be used for subsequent access to the file.  On failure, it returns -1;

When the file is open, you can use `read()` and `write()` to manipulate the contents.

Be sure to call `close()` and pass in the return value from open when you are done with the file.

Your example above would look something like this:

```
int main()
{
  char buf [255];
  int tst;
  int dsply = open(DEV_CONSOLE , 0);
  //next we will open the file.  We will want to read and write, so we use
  // O_RDWR.  If the files does not already exist, we want to create it, so
  // we use O_CREAT.  If the file *DOES* already exist, we want to truncate
  // and start fresh, so we delete all previous contents with O_TRUNC
  tst = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

  // always check the return value.
  if(tst < 0)
  {
     write(dsply, "ERROR!", 6);
     return 0;
  }
  strcpy(buf, "this text should write in file.")
  write(tst, buf, strlen(buf));
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  read(tst, buf, 30);
  //be sure to close when you are done
  close(tst);

  write(dsply,buf,strlen(buf));
  //you'll want to close your devices, as well
  close(dsply);
  return 0;
}
```

Your comments also ask about searching.  For that, you'll also need to use `lseek` with one of the following which specifies where you are starting from:

- `SEEK_SET` — Beginning of file
- `SEEK_CUR` — Current seek pointer location
- `SEEK_END` — End of file

example

```
SomeDataStruct myData;
...
//assume "curPosition" is set to the beginning of the next data structure I want to read
lseek(file, curPosition, SEEK_SET);
result = read(file, (char*)&myData, sizeof(SomeDataStruct));
curPosition += sizeof(SomeDataStruct);
//now "curPosition" is ready to pull out the next data structure.
```

NOTE that the internal file pointer is already AT "curPosition", but doing it this way allows me to move forward and backward at will as I manipulate what is there.  So, for example, if I wanted to move back to the previous data structure, I would simply set "curPosition" as follows:

```
curPosition -= 2 * sizeof(SomeDataStruct);
```

If I didn't want to keep track of "curPosition", I could also do the following which would also move the internal file pointer to the correct place:

```
lseek(file, - (2 * sizeof(SomeDataStruct)), SEEK_CUR);
```

You get to pick whichever method works best for you.